# How to use a calculated column by another calculated column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a query in Sqlite that involves a complicated column calculation, let's say:

```
SELECT 1+1 AS a;
```

I want to have this calculation selected as `a`, but I also need to use it as a component of another calculation:

```
SELECT 1+1 AS a, a+2 AS b;
```

Unfortunately this produces the error:

```
Error: no such column: a
```

I know that I could simply repeat the calculation again for `b`:

```
SELECT 1+1 AS a, 1+1+2 AS b;
```

But assuming `1+1` is some complicated and expensive operation, is there any way that I can reference it later in the `SELECT` without having to recalculate it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a calculated column to calculate another column in the same view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185043/how-to-use-a-calculated-column-to-calculate-another-column-in-the-same-view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a sub-query.

```
SELECT c.d AS a, c.d + 2 AS b
FROM
  (SELECT 1+1 AS d) c
```

**Result**

```
| a | b |
---------
| 2 | 4 |
```

Comment: @twoleggedhorse Thanks, missed that part.

Comment: @njk: Nice but same alias for table and column? Ouch.

Comment: Where exactly is table name specified?

Comment: @Mercurial Table name of what?

Answer (score 0):

See if you can do it something like this (using a subquery for the table)

```
Select t.a+2 as b
    FROM (Select 1+1 as a from xyz) t
```

Comment: The OP wants to have `a` returned as well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all nice examples by others - this works in Oracle:

```
SELECT a, a+2 b From
(
 SELECT 1+1 a From dual
)
/

Output:

A | B
-----
2 | 4
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately `dual` isn't supported by Sqlite.