# How to use a calculated column to calculate another column in the same view

Tags: sql, oracle

I am hoping you can help with this question.  I am using Oracle SQL (SQL Developer for this view)...

If I have a table with the following columns:

- ColumnA (Number)
- ColumnB (Number)
- ColumnC (Number)

In my view I have

```
Select  
ColumnA,
ColumnB,
ColumnA + ColumnB As calccolumn1
```

Now at this point, I want to use calccolumn1
but I cannot just say...

```
Select  
ColumnA,
ColumnB,
ColumnA + ColumnB As calccolumn1
calccolumn1 / ColumnC as calccolumn2
```

I am assuming I need some type of subquery..but this is where I need your help...
How would I word the query so that I can use calccolumn1 in another calculation within the same query?  It might be an If then or a Case when, but bottomline it is some derived number.

Comment: Is there a reason not to just do `(ColumnA + ColumnB) / ColumnC As calccolumn2`?

Comment: I agree...in this simplified example..that would work fine.  I was trying to get to the concept of how I would format a simplied example to apply to a more complex one...so if ColumnA was a complex Case When statement and ColumnB was also...then if I want to combined them to produce calccolumn1 and later use to calccolumn2.  Would I simply just put the entire Case state for Column A in () and the same for B and add them?

Comment: @AlexPoole Having complex expression on the same level could be handy. Single  definition is easier to maintain than copying it over multiple places. It is doable using [`CROSS APPLY approach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52024045/5070879)

Comment: Of course, the question just didn't show a complex expression really. I was going to say cross apply wasn't available when the question was asked, but 12c had been out a few months by then, I just wasn't aware of it... The subquery approach doesn't repeat it either though.

Comment: @AlexPoole There is nothing wrong with inline view/CTE approach. I just wanted to show that it is possible to have complex expression at the same query level as alternative.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You could use a nested query:

```
Select
  ColumnA,
  ColumnB,
  calccolumn1,
  calccolumn1 / ColumnC as calccolumn2
From (
  Select
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    ColumnC,
    ColumnA + ColumnB As calccolumn1
  from t42
);
```

With a row with values `3`, `4`, `5` that gives:

```
   COLUMNA    COLUMNB CALCCOLUMN1 CALCCOLUMN2
---------- ---------- ----------- -----------
         3          4           7         1.4
```

You can also just repeat the first calculation, unless it's really doing something expensive (via a function call, say):

```
Select
  ColumnA,
  ColumnB,
  ColumnA + ColumnB As calccolumn1,
  (ColumnA + ColumnB) / ColumnC As calccolumn2
from t42; 

   COLUMNA    COLUMNB CALCCOLUMN1 CALCCOLUMN2
---------- ---------- ----------- -----------
         3          4           7         1.4
```

Answer (score 36):

**In Sql Server**

You can do this using `cross apply`

```
Select
  ColumnA,
  ColumnB,
  c.calccolumn1 As calccolumn1,
  c.calccolumn1 / ColumnC As calccolumn2
from t42
cross apply (select (ColumnA + ColumnB) as calccolumn1) as c
```

Answer (score 18):

If you want to refer to calculated column on the "same query level" then you could use `CROSS APPLY`(Oracle 12c):

```
--Sample data:
CREATE TABLE tab(ColumnA NUMBER(10,2),ColumnB NUMBER(10,2),ColumnC NUMBER(10,2));

INSERT INTO tab(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC) VALUES (2, 10, 2);
INSERT INTO tab(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC) VALUES (3, 15, 6);
INSERT INTO tab(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC) VALUES (7, 14, 3);
COMMIT;
```

Query:

```
SELECT
  ColumnA,
  ColumnB,
  sub.calccolumn1,
  sub.calccolumn1 / ColumnC AS calccolumn2
FROM tab t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.ColumnA + t.ColumnB AS calccolumn1 FROM dual) sub;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=f8c99cd360d1acccfaea34b169c2933f)**

---

Please note that expression from `CROSS APPLY/OUTER APPLY` is available in other clauses too:

```
SELECT
  ColumnA,
  ColumnB,
  sub.calccolumn1,
  sub.calccolumn1 / ColumnC AS calccolumn2
FROM tab t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.ColumnA + t.ColumnB AS calccolumn1 FROM dual) sub
WHERE sub.calccolumn1 = 12;
-- GROUP BY ...
-- ORDER BY ...;
```

This approach allows to avoid wrapping entire query with outerquery or copy/paste same expression in multiple places(with complex one it could be hard to maintain).

Related article: [The SQL Language’s Most Missing Feature](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/01/06/the-sql-languages-most-missing-feature/#comment-208085)

Answer (score 8):

You have to include the expression for your calculated column:

```
SELECT  
ColumnA,  
ColumnB,  
ColumnA + ColumnB AS calccolumn1  
(ColumnA + ColumnB) / ColumnC AS calccolumn2
```

Comment: Or you could create a stored procedure to output the column calcolumn1

Comment: This is just a copy of part of a prior answer.

Answer (score 3):

**In SQL Server**


You can do this using **With CTE**

[WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
CREATE TABLE tab(ColumnA DECIMAL(10,2), ColumnB DECIMAL(10,2), ColumnC DECIMAL(10,2))

INSERT INTO tab(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC) VALUES (2, 10, 2),(3, 15, 6),(7, 14, 3)

WITH tab_CTE (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC,calccolumn1)  
AS  
(  
Select
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    ColumnC,
    ColumnA + ColumnB As calccolumn1
  from tab
)  

SELECT
  ColumnA,
  ColumnB,
  calccolumn1,
  calccolumn1 / ColumnC AS calccolumn2
FROM  tab_CTE
```

[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=40b1e171cb1aeac9e1390a0a20f11905)