# How to get average of columns?

Tags: sql

I have a query where I get the average for each rating 1-5 from each month.
What I would like to do is get the average of all the months using those averages I first get.

for example if the query below outputs the data for q1-q5:
(1,4,1,4,3)= 1+4+1+4+3=13/5=2.6

I would like a query where I can get the 2.6 output.

I made some sample data:

```
create table CSEReduxResponses (employeedept int, rating1 int, rating2 int, rating3 int, rating4 int,
rating5 int,approveddate datetime, execoffice_status int);
-- all columns for the table will never be null
insert into CSEReduxResponses (employeedept, rating1, rating2,rating3,rating4,rating5,approveddate,execoffice_status)
values (1 , 1 ,4,1,2,5,'2014-05-01',1),
(1 , 1 ,4,1,4,4,'2014-05-01',1),
(1 , 1 ,4,2,0,5,'2014-05-01',1),
(1 , 1 ,4,2,4,0,'2014-05-01',1),
(1 , 1 ,4,1,2,5,'2014-05-01',1),
(1 , 1 ,4,1,4,3,'2014-06-01',1),
(2 , 4 ,4,2,5,3,'2014-06-01',1),
(2 , 3 ,4,2,4,0,'2014-06-01',1),
(2 , 3 ,4,5,5,0,'2014-06-01',1),
(3 , 0 ,4,5,3,5,'2014-07-01',1);

create table CSEReduxDepts (csedept_id int, csedept_name varchar(25));
insert into CSEReduxDepts (csedept_id, csedept_name)
values (1,'department 1'),
(2,'department 2'),
(3,'department 3'),
(4,'department 4');
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT CAST(employeedept AS INT) as dept,
    ROUND(AVG(case when rating1>0 THEN CAST(rating1 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q1,
    ROUND(AVG(case when rating2>0 THEN CAST(rating2 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q2,
    ROUND(AVG(case when rating3>0 THEN CAST(rating3 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q3,
    ROUND(AVG(case when rating4>0 THEN CAST(rating4 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q4,
    ROUND(AVG(case when rating5>0 THEN CAST(rating5 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q5,
    count(*) as 'totalstars',month_cse= datename(month,approveddate),YEAR_cse =YEAR(approveddate)

    FROM CSEReduxResponses
    WHERE execoffice_status = 1
    and YEAR ([approveddate]) =2014

group by month(approveddate),YEAR(approveddate),DATENAME(month,approveddate),employeedept
    order by month_cse
```

What I would like to see its show the average of the rating1-5 that I get with the query above.

I made this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c9811/1
so basically i want to get the average for q1-q5 using these results i get.
[image]

from the results above then in would be
for the first row:
null(0)+4+5+3+5=3.4
for the second row:
1+4+1+4+3=13/5=2.6
and so on,
so I would like to show these averages.

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Comment: I mean, can you show us an example of the output based on the scripts above.

Comment: If you're averaging some averages, it will yield the same results as just averaging the whole set together

Comment: @J-Dizzle That only works simply if each subset being averaged has the same number of items in it, and `case when rating#>0` implies that that isn't the case here. That means using a weighted average, at which point the sql query becomes complicated enough you don't save yourself any time over just averaging the averages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're after, but I believe the "WITH" clause will help you out.

```
;
WITH tmp AS (
SELECT CAST(employeedept AS INT) as dept,
    ROUND(AVG(case when rating1>0 THEN CAST(rating1 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q1,
    ROUND(AVG(case when rating2>0 THEN CAST(rating2 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q2,
    ROUND(AVG(case when rating3>0 THEN CAST(rating3 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q3,
    ROUND(AVG(case when rating4>0 THEN CAST(rating4 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q4,
    ROUND(AVG(case when rating5>0 THEN CAST(rating5 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q5,
    count(*) as 'totalstars',month_cse= datename(month,approveddate),YEAR_cse =YEAR(approveddate)

    FROM CSEReduxResponses
    WHERE execoffice_status = 1
    and YEAR ([approveddate]) =2014

group by month(approveddate),YEAR(approveddate),DATENAME(month,approveddate),employeedept
)
SELECT dept, q1 + q2 + q3 + q4+ q5 / 5
FROM tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

See "[How to use a calculated column to calculate another column in the same view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185043/how-to-use-a-calculated-column-to-calculate-another-column-in-the-same-view)" for more options, but I'd suggest a nested query:

```
SELECT q1,
    q2,
    q3,
    q4,
    q5,
    (q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5)/5 as avgQ,
    totalstars,
    month_cse,
    YEAR_cse

FROM (SELECT CAST(employeedept AS INT) as dept,
          ROUND(AVG(case when rating1>0 THEN CAST(rating1 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q1,
          ROUND(AVG(case when rating2>0 THEN CAST(rating2 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q2,
          ROUND(AVG(case when rating3>0 THEN CAST(rating3 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q3,
          ROUND(AVG(case when rating4>0 THEN CAST(rating4 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q4,
          ROUND(AVG(case when rating5>0 THEN CAST(rating5 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q5,
          count(*) as 'totalstars',month_cse= datename(month,approveddate),YEAR_cse= YEAR(approveddate)

      FROM CSEReduxResponses
      WHERE execoffice_status = 1
      and YEAR ([approveddate]) =2014

      group by month(approveddate),YEAR(approveddate),DATENAME(month,approveddate),employeedept
     )

    order by month_cse
```

That's untested, so there may be some issues, but it gets you on the right track.