# Use of dynamically created columns prompts "Invalid Column"Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create new column by performing some addition, multiplication and subtraction with the values of the columns that is already created with the MS SQL table . In the below code, I created [PremiumByCodes] col. by doing the calculation. Likewise, when I try to create col. [Commission] , it shows me, **invalid column name "PremiumBYCodes"**. I also wanted to do the same kind of multiplication to Deduction column and create a new column.  Any suggestions, on how to proceed by doing this ?

```
     select 

     [PremiumByCodes]  = a.[NWP]/(1-c.[Commission%]-c.[Deduction%]),    

     [Commission] = [PremiumByCodes] /c.[Commission%], 

     [Deduction] = [PremiumByCodes] /c.[Deduction%],
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185043/how-to-use-a-calculated-column-to-calculate-another-column-in-the-same-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sure looks like SQL Server code.

First, databases just do not allow re-using column aliases in the same `SELECT` where they are defined.  The normal approach is to use a subquery or CTE.  Another approach uses lateral joins, which is implemented in SQL Server using `APPLY`:

```
select v.PremiumByCodes, v.PremiumByCodes / c.[Commission%] as Commission,
       v.PremiumByCodes /c.[Deduction%] as Deduction, 
       . . .
from . . . outer apply
     (values (a.[BHSINWP]/(1-c.[Commission%]-c.[Deduction%]) )) v(PremiumByCodes)
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

In sql-server, you can not reference a column by its alias except for in the `order by` of your query.

```
select 
    [PremiumByCodes] = a.[BHSINWP]/(1-c.[Commission%]-c.[Deduction%])
  , [Commission] = (a.[BHSINWP]/(1-c.[Commission%]-c.[Deduction%]))/c.[Commission%]
  , [Deduction]  = (a.[BHSINWP]/(1-c.[Commission%]-c.[Deduction%]))/c.[Deduction%]
```