# How to create a new value our of the number of rows times another value

Tags: sql

I want to create a new value, TotalPrice, out of the number of passengers times the CruisePrice. I have the following which isn't working:

```
SELECT PlaceResidency, BirthDate, LastName, FirstName
    , (SELECT count (*) AS "PassengerAmount" FROM PASSENGER)
    , PassengerAmount * CruisePrise AS TotalPrice
FROM PASSENGER, PERSON, CRUISE 
WHERE BirthDate >= 18
ORDER BY PlaceResidency, BirthDate, TotalPrice;
```

Comment: Update the tags.  It looks like you are using SQL Server.

Comment: please give sample data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a calculated column to calculate another column in the same view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185043/how-to-use-a-calculated-column-to-calculate-another-column-in-the-same-view)

Comment: Note that each row of your query will have the same PassengerAmount - the count of records in the Passenger table - as there are no constraints on the subquery - is that what you want.

Comment: Could you provide some relationship between the Person, Passenger and Cruise tables? You might need to use joins for your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395)?

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a variable to hold the count of passengers and use it wherever needed to avoid recounting in subquery.

```
DECLARE @PassengersCount INT = (SELECT count (*)  FROM PASSENGER);

SELECT PlaceResidency, BirthDate, LastName, FirstName, @PassengersCount AS 
PassengerAmount, @PassengersCount * CruisePrise AS TotalPrice
FROM PERSON, CRUISE
WHERE BirthDate >= 18
ORDER BY PlaceResidency, BirthDate, TotalPrice;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution maybe it works :

```
SELECT PlaceResidency, BirthDate, LastName, FirstName
    , (SELECT count (*)  FROM PASSENGER) AS PassengerAmount
    , ((SELECT count (*)  FROM PASSENGER) * CruisePrise )AS TotalPrice
FROM PASSENGER, PERSON, CRUISE 
WHERE BirthDate >= 18
ORDER BY PlaceResidency, BirthDate, TotalPrice;
```

Comment: That would work - but the subquery would be performed twice which may affect performance - a nested query, as per the last answer in the duplicate question, maybe would be better.