# Dividing Data Records

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have case when expression showing me the number total for a certain type of task that employees do.

```
select 
  ptt.user_id
  /*System Generated Counts*/ , 
  count(distinct case
    when menu_optn_name in ('Cycle Cnt {Active}','Cycle Cnt {Reserve}','Cycle Cnt Reserve (Tasking)') and task_id is not null then tran_nbr
    else null
  end) "Task Cnt"
  /*Spot Counts*/ , 
  count(distinct case
    when menu_optn_name in ('Cycle Cnt {Active}','Cycle Cnt {Reserve}') and task_id is null then tran_nbr
    else null
  end) "Spot_Counts", 
  count(distinct case
    when menu_optn_name in ('Cycle Cnt {Active}','Cycle Cnt {Reserve}','Cycle Cnt Reserve (Tasking)') and task_id is not null then tran_nbr
    when menu_optn_name in ('Cycle Cnt {Active}','Cycle Cnt {Reserve}','Cycle Cnt Reserve (Tasking)') and task_id is null then tran_nbr
    else null
  end) "Total_locations", 
  count(case
    when menu_optn_name in ('Cycle Cnt {Active}','Cycle Cnt {Reserve}','Cycle Cnt Reserve (Tasking)') and task_id is not null then tran_nbr
    when menu_optn_name in ('Cycle Cnt {Active}','Cycle Cnt {Reserve}','Cycle Cnt Reserve (Tasking)') and task_id is null then tran_nbr
    else null
  end) "Total_Cases"
from PROD_TRKG_TRAN ptt
  join cd_master cm on
    ptt.cd_master_id = cm.cd_master_id 
    and co = 'MEDT' 
    and div = '002' 
    and ptt.USER_ID in ('ARAMOS1','ECHAMBERS','SCOUNCIL','STORTEROTOT','TGABRIEL','JORTIZ','FGUTIERREZ','CMALDONADO','LLEE1') 
    and ptt.create_date_time >= 
/*Today*/ trunc(sysdate) 
--/*This Week*/              trunc(sysdate-(to_char(sysdate,'D')-1))
--/*This Month*/            trunc(sysdate)-(to_char(sysdate,'DD')-1)
--/*Date Range*/            '&FromDate' and ptt.create_date_time-1 < '&ToDate'
group by ptt.user_id
```

Above is my current SQL, the top 2 case when expression are calculation how many locations an employee counted based on specific selector is null or not. 
The next 2 case when expression are combining them two to give you the total distinct locations that were counted by a certain person the whole night, the next expression shows you the total cases counted, sometimes there are more then one case in a location.

My goal here is to take the total number of locations and cases and have them divided by 7 1/2 hours so I can see how many an individual is averaging per hour for the day.
I have tried some random stuff with no luck at all. Possibly someone can assist. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Possibly someone can assist." With sample data maybe so (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements) ;)

Comment: So you want to divide each `count()` by 7.5? It isn't clear why that is a problem.

Comment: Alex Poole it’s the issue due to me not being able to figure out the expression logic to have it calculate it. Basically the reason is if someone counts 50 location then divide that by 7.5 it would tell me there average counts be hours.

Comment: Well, [the arithmetic operators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Arithmetic-Operators.html) are pretty standard... so `count(case ... end)/7.5`. Are you really just asking for that, or something more than you've said? (Like, rather than fixed 7.5, use the current time which may less that that; or include the number of days for the commented-out ranges; or just [avoid repeating the count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19185374/266304)?)

Comment: Alex Poole so do count(case
    when menu_optn_name in ('Cycle Cnt {Active}','Cycle Cnt {Reserve}','Cycle Cnt Reserve (Tasking)') and task_id is not null then tran_nbr
    when menu_optn_name in ('Cycle Cnt {Active}','Cycle Cnt {Reserve}','Cycle Cnt Reserve (Tasking)') and task_id is null then tran_nbr
    else null
  end) / 7.5 "Total_Cases” ... if so I kinda feel stupid haha still learning, everything I’ve learned has just been from work so not really exposed to a lot. Anyways what we’re referring to about the current time and stuff?