# Oracle SQL Calculated Column - How do I reference a calculated column in another calculation in the same query?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pandas, plsql

I want to use a calculated column in another calculation, within the same query.  But Oracle SQL does not seem to let me do this, to my knowledge.  These seems like a simple data maneuver, that i can easily do in Python, but Oracle SQL it seems challenging.

For example:

**table**

date | value1 | value2

**Desired Query Functionality**

```
SELECT
date,
value1,
value2,
(value2 * value1) AS value_calculated
(value_calculated * 100) AS value_calculated_2
(value_calculated_2 * 1000) AS value_calculated_3

FROM  table
```

If this is not possible, I think Oracle should build in this into their software.

In other Stack Overflow questions/responses, CROSS APPLY has come up.  This is not working for me, since I have 10-20 calculated columns I need to create (all of which reference the other calculated columns).

Is there a simple PL/SQL function i can create to designate these as objects to use in other column calculations?

**UPDATE TO QUESTION:**

Here is the full code of what I'm doing, using Oracle Cloud Financials 19C

```
WITH segment_desc AS(
SELECT DISTINCT
flex_value,
description
FROM
fnd_flex_values_vl
WHERE description NOT IN('Default')

),
balances_calc AS(
SELECT
gl_balances.period_name,
gl_ledgers.ledger_id,
gl_ledgers.name,
gl_ledgers.currency_code||'-'||gl_balances.currency_code 
func_ent_curr_pair,
gl_code_combinations.code_combination_id,
gl_code_combinations.segment1,
gl_code_combinations.segment2,
segment_desc.description center_description,
gl_code_combinations.segment3,
gl_code_combinations.segment4,
gl_code_combinations.segment5,

gl_balances.currency_code ent_curr_cd,
-- balance logic swap functional/entered if ent=func
CASE
    WHEN gl_balances.currency_code = gl_ledgers.currency_code
        THEN NVL(gl_balances.begin_balance_dr_beq,0) - 
NVL(gl_balances.begin_balance_cr_beq,0) -- return functional "beq"
                ELSE NVL(gl_balances.begin_balance_dr,0) - 
NVL(gl_balances.begin_balance_cr,0) -- return entered "balances_cr/dr"
                    END
ent_beg_balance,

-- activity logic swap functional/entered if func=ent
CASE
    WHEN gl_balances.currency_code = gl_ledgers.currency_code
    THEN NVL(gl_balances.period_net_dr_beq,0) - 
NVL(gl_balances.period_net_cr_beq,0)   -- return functional "beq"
                ELSE NVL(gl_balances.period_net_dr,0) - 
NVL(gl_balances.period_net_cr,0) -- return entered "balances_cr/dr"
                    END
ent_activity,

gl_ledgers.currency_code func_curr_cd,

NVL(gl_balances.begin_balance_dr_beq,0) - 
NVL(gl_balances.begin_balance_cr_beq,0) func_beg_balance,
NVL(gl_balances.period_net_dr_beq,0) - 
NVL(gl_balances.period_net_cr_beq,0) func_activity,

-- if statement currency equals
CASE
    WHEN gl_balances.currency_code = gl_ledgers.currency_code
        THEN 'TRUE'
                ELSE 'FALSE'
                    END
entered_equals_functional,
gl_balances.translated_flag

FROM
gl_balances, gl_code_combinations, gl_ledgers, segment_desc
WHERE
1 = 1
AND gl_code_combinations.chart_of_accounts_id = '2001'
AND (gl_balances.translated_flag IN ('N','R') OR 
gl_balances.translated_flag IS NULL)
AND gl_balances.code_combination_id = 
gl_code_combinations.code_combination_id
AND gl_ledgers.ledger_id = gl_balances.ledger_id
AND  segment_desc.flex_value (+) = gl_code_combinations.segment2

),


balances_calc_test AS(
SELECT 
balances_calc.period_name,
balances_calc.segment1,
balances_calc.segment2,
balances_calc.segment3,
balances_calc.segment4,
**calc_column.func_end_balance,**
**calc_column_2.custom_calc**

FROM balances_calc

**CROSS APPLY(SELECT func_beg_balance + func_activity AS func_end_balance 
FROM balances_calc) calc_column**
**CROSS APPLY(SELECT func_end_balance - ent_activity AS custom_calc FROM 
balances_calc) calc_column_2**
)

SELECT * FROM balances_calc_test
```

**This returns errors in the query**

I get repeating values in the **calc_column.func_end_balance** column.

Should I use a WHERE statement to join?

Again, I think there needs to be an easier solution to having derived column calculations.  Python Pandas can do this in 2 seconds.

Comment: You need to use a subquery, CTE, or lateral join.

Comment: thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: @JesseNicholson I doubt there is any SQL implementation that allows this. The SQL language in general doesn't like to be told what order to do things in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *In other Stack Overflow questions/responses, CROSS APPLY has come up. This is not working for me, since I have 10-20 calculated columns I need to create (all of which reference the other calculated columns).*

`CROSS APPLY` could be chained:

```
SELECT t.*, s1.val1, s2.val2, s3.val3
FROM tab t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.val1 * t.val2 AS val3 FROM dual) s1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT s1.val3 * 100   AS val4 FROM dual) s2
CROSS APPLY (SELECT s2.val4 * 1000  AS val5 FROM dual) s3
--...
```

All you need is to make sure that you are referencing objects in correct order.

Related:

[How to use a calculated column to calculate another column in the same view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185043/how-to-use-a-calculated-column-to-calculate-another-column-in-the-same-view/52024045#52024045)

Comment: thank you! very helpful, i think this will solve my dilemma.  I was using a WITH clause, and joining two tables.  What I think I will do is, join the two tables, then use another WITH clause to perform the CROSS APPLY's, where I need to add 10-20 calculations.  It think this will work perfect, thanks so much.

Comment: Can you please clarify what the "dual" table is in your code that you have above?  You have FROM dual table in the CROSS apply. @Lukasz Szozda

Comment: If using CROSS APPLY method, i try to reference calculated columns from s1 and tab t, i get duplicate values.  should i include a WHERE statement and set the s1,s2,s3 tables equal to eachother for an inner join?  i.e. s1.id = t.id? I'll post some example code and output too. thanks for your help.  this one is a doozy. @ Lukasz Szozda

Comment: @JesseNicholson Oracle SQL syntax requires a 'from' clause. Therefore the system dummy table `dual` is provided so that you can efficiently `select from` something.

Comment: @JesseNicholson `i get duplicate values` 1) Please make sure you are using proper join instead of comma syntax 2) set your query as `SELECT ... FROM JOIN JOIN JOIN CROSS APPLY ... CROSS APPLY CROSS APPLY` and in every cross apply work in context of row(using `FROM DUAL`) instead of refering another table. If you decide to use your way then yes, you need to correlate the main table with table references inside CROSSS APPLY.

Comment: @ Lukasz Szozda , I'm so sorry, I did not understand the dual table!  I should have followed your first instructions.  This appears to be working now!  I will post final code to show output.  Thank you so much!!!!!!! This will be used in production code for hundreds of people to run Oracle Cloud reports, thank you, much appreciated!  @ William Robertson -- thank you for jumping in and clarifying, I think I got it.  will post final code later and classify this post as solved! Hopefully this helps other people too.

Comment: @JesseNicholson Really glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 2):

This is standard SQL functionality and it is defined as such for a good reason:  databases are not required to evaluate the `select` expressions in any order.  So, there is no "before" aliases to look at.

The normal solution is a CTE or subquery:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (value_calculated_2 * 1000) AS value_calculated_3
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (value_calculated * 100) AS value_calculated_2 
      FROM (SELECT date, value1, value2,
                   (value2 * value1) AS value_calculated
            FROM . . . 
           ) t
     ) t
```