# Using the result from a subquery elsewhere in the query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following pseudo-sqlite call:

```
SELECT x, y,
    (SELECT --very long SQL call--) AS z,
    (SELECT a FROM diff_table_name WHERE b = z) AS e
FROM table_name
WHERE c = d
```

Essentially I want to use the `z` variable result from the first *subquery* in the second *subquery*, but I get a

> no such column: z

error when I do.  I can repeat the very long SQL call in the second *subquery* and that works, but I was hoping to not have to do that.  Or maybe there's a way to return both `a` and `z` from one *subquery*?

Comment: Is your very long SQL call a correlated subquery?  Can you post the real query plus some sample data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just commented to your post that I believe it is a correlated subquery.  As far as posting the real query... there's so much extraneous stuff unrelated to the question at hand, I'd feel the need to edit it.  Either way... I was hoping for an easy answer that I just wasn't aware of... it's not horrible if I just have the long subquery used twice in the call... I was just thinking/hoping there was a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: You may rewrite the query to use a join instead of a correlated subquery.  But I can't offer a solution without seeing the real code; what you posted is way too generic.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19185043, https://stackoverflow.com/q/57021788

Answer (score 1):

This part of your query:

```
SELECT x, y,
  (SELECT --very long SQL call--) AS z
FROM table_name
WHERE c = d
```

can be safely wrapped inside a CTE and then use the value of `z`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT x, y,
    (SELECT --very long SQL call--) AS z
  FROM table_name
  WHERE c = d
)
SELECT x, y, z,
  (SELECT a FROM diff_table_name WHERE b = z) AS e
FROM cte
```