# Re-using computed columns in the same query for other calculation

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have to use computed columns to yet calculate the value of another column. Because I work with a very large table and also doing complex computation for the two previous columns, it wouldn't be a good idea to repeat the same functions to derive the third column, so looking for a way to use sub-query.

My table:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 5;
 session_id |  seconds   | millis |  gpstime   | gpsmillis | nsats |    lat     |    lon     | alt | track |  speed  | acc 
------------+------------+--------+------------+-----------+-------+------------+------------+-----+-------+---------+-----
      14026 | 1460464791 |    264 | 1460464791 |       264 |    -1 |  41.178237 | -8.5947137 |   0 |     0 |       0 |  20
      14026 | 1460464983 |    970 | 1460464983 |       970 |    -1 |  41.177956 | -8.5953581 | 234 |    67 | 10.2583 |  25
      14026 | 1460464984 |    712 | 1460464984 |       712 |    -1 | 41.1780008 | -8.5952012 | 182 |    58 | 9.19696 |  31
      14026 | 1460464985 |    700 | 1460464985 |       700 |    -1 | 41.1779522 |  -8.595209 | 196 |    74 | 7.63053 |  19
      14026 | 1460464986 |    714 | 1460464986 |       714 |    -1 |  41.177981 | -8.5951491 | 196 |    74 | 5.51359 |  22
(5 rows)
```

Then I run the query below to compute `a1` and `a2` in a subquery and averaged them in the main query as `acceleration`.

```
SELECT session_id
    , gpstime
    , lat
    , lon
    , track AS heading
    , speed
    , AVG(a1, a2) AS acceleration
FROM (
        SELECT *
            ,((LEAD(speed) OVER (ORDER BY gpstime)) - speed) / 
               (((LEAD(gpstime) OVER (ORDER BY gpstime)) - gpstime) +0.001) AS a2
        , (speed - (LAG(speed) OVER (ORDER BY gpstime))) / 
                     (gpstime - (LAG(gpstime) OVER (ORDER BY gpstime)) + 0.001) AS a1
        FROM my_table
    );
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 9:  (
         ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
SQL state: 42601
Character: 111
```

I also added an alias to my subquery, yet that didn't work.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185043/how-to-use-a-calculated-column-to-calculate-another-column-in-the-same-view?answertab=active#tab-top), which seems to work for Oracle database, but this doesn't work in my case(using PostgreSQL). I reproduce a minimal working example in a fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d800a34f2508cae04082f50e40629e84) to illustrate the problem.

Can someone point out what I missed or did wrong here?

Comment: It works fine with a table alias:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d800a34f2508cae04082f50e40629e84.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint tells you what to do: give the sub-query an alias:

```
SELECT session_id
    , gpstime
    , lat
    , lon
    , track AS heading
    , speed
    , AVG(a1) AS acceleration
FROM (
        SELECT *
            ,((LEAD(speed) OVER (ORDER BY gpstime)) - speed) / 
               (((LEAD(gpstime) OVER (ORDER BY gpstime)) - gpstime) +0.001) AS a2
        , (speed - (LAG(speed) OVER (ORDER BY gpstime))) / 
                     (gpstime - (LAG(gpstime) OVER (ORDER BY gpstime)) + 0.001) AS a1
        FROM my_table
    ) as sub; --<< HERE
```

But `AVG(a1, a2)` is also wrong.

`avg()` is an aggregate function that works on a single column and separate rows. So you either need to use `avg(a1)` or `avg(a2)` or maybe you want `(a1 + a2) / 2` if you want the average between the two values.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=45360e4caa3af6edcfd3b268ffe3633e)

Comment: Ah, thank you for your answer. I was placing the subquery alias within the parenthesis.