# CROSS APPLY for CASE expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Is there any value in using a CROSS APPLY to encapsulate CASE expression(s). Let me explain the question with an example.

**Data Setup**

```
DECLARE @data AS TABLE([id] INT IDENTITY(1,1), [value] BIGINT);
INSERT INTO @data([value])
VALUES (100), (200), (7), (128), (315);
```

**Query #1**

The following query uses a traditional pattern of CASE expressions in the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT [id]
, [value]
, CASE WHEN [value] < 100 THEN 'CLASS-C'
    WHEN [value] < 200 THEN 'CLASS-B'
    ELSE 'CLASS-A' END AS [rating]
FROM @data
```

**Query #2**

Encapsulates the CASE expression in an APPLY

```
SELECT [id]
, [value]
, [rating]
FROM @data
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN [value] < 100 THEN 'CLASS-C'
    WHEN [value] < 200 THEN 'CLASS-B'
    ELSE 'CLASS-A' END AS [rating]) AS [applied]
```

**Basic Analysis**

Results of both queries are the same and the execution plan is also similar.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: `CASE` **expression**, SQL Server does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Comment: @Larnu, took me a minute to understand that but when I did, I felt like my eyes opened afresh! Thank you, made the change.

Comment: Yes, CROSS APPLY is very convinient way of introducing calculated expression "at the same level" as main query. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52024045/5070879). It resembles `LET` clause known from other languages(LINQ/XQUERY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer `rating` multiple times in the `SELECT`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, or later in the `FROM` clause.

This is a convenient way to define columns referred to multiple times.