# Sum two SQLite columns, when they're subqueries

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table of receipts. Each one is associated with a service, and each person is obligated to pay equally for it, except when they are assigned an extra fee that can be activated/deactivaded (0/1). So I used a subquery to get the extra amount they have to pay only if that fee is active; the table *'fees'* contains the *user_id*, the *service_id*, the extra amount and the active flag. And then, I should get the total per person, adding the extra fee (if any) to the subtotal (receipt total amount minus any active extra fee, and then divided by the number of persons who are obligated to contribute).

```
SELECT
    P.nombre AS person,
    S.nombre AS service,
    (
        SELECT TOTAL(C.value)
        FROM fees C
        WHERE C.user_id = P.id AND C.service_id = O.service_id AND C.active = 0
    ) AS fee,
    IFNULL(NULL, 23333) AS subtotal,
    (fee + subtotal) as total
FROM receipts R
    LEFT JOIN obligations O ON O.service_id = R.service_id
    LEFT JOIN persons P ON O.user_id = P.id
    LEFT JOIN services S ON O.service_id = S.id
WHERE R.id = 3 AND O.active = 0;
```

*Note: 23333 (the subtotal) will be replaced with a '?' and then I'll pass as argument to execute the query with Golang that result that I've already got from another function*

Problem occurs at this line

```
(fee + subtotal) as total
```

Output: **no such column: fee**

If I run the query without that line, it will actually return a table with the active extra fees and subtotal, but I'm stuck when trying to create a final column to add those two values.

[image: screen capture of the table without the 'total' column]

Thanks!

---

**Edit**

Following Stefan's advice, here are the statements I used to create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS persons (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL, active INTEGER DEFAULT 0); CREATE UNIQUE INDEX per_nom_uindex on persons (name)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS services (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL, active INTEGER  DEFAULT 0); CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ser_nom_uindex on services (name)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS receipts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, y INTEGER NOT NULL, m INTEGER NOT NULL, service_id INTEGER NOT NULL, amount INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (service_id) REFERENCES services (id))

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fees (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, person_id INTEGER NOT NULL, service_id INTEGER NOT NULL, amount INTEGER NOT NULL, active INTEGER DEFAULT 0, FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES persons(id), FOREIGN KEY(service_id) REFERENCES services(id))

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS obligations (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, person_id INTEGER NOT NULL, service_id INTEGER NOT NULL, active INTEGER DEFAULT 0, FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES persons(id), FOREIGN KEY(service_id) REFERENCES services(id))
```

Comment: In `SELECT ... AS a, ... AS b FROM ...`, the name a is not visible to expressions in the rest of the query, including the expression given the name b.

Comment: You need a CTE/subquery to compute everything but total, and get that figure in the top level select.

Comment: If you add the five prerequisite `Create Table...` statements, readers would have less work when they want to help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a calculated column to calculate another column in the same view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185043/how-to-use-a-calculated-column-to-calculate-another-column-in-the-same-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider moving the subquery from `SELECT` to `JOIN` clause (often called derived table) and adjust it with `GROUP BY` aggregation on `user_id` and `service_id`. Doing so, this allows you to reference the column as needed and even avoid rowwise aggregation (unless the SQLite engine runs it as a single aggregation under the hood).

```sql
SELECT
    P.nombre AS person,
    S.nombre AS service,
    C.fee,                                  -- REFERENCE SUBQUERY COLUMN
    IFNULL(?, 23333) AS subtotal,
    C.fee + IFNULL(?, 23333) as total       -- REPEAT NEEDED EXPRESSION
FROM receipts R
    LEFT JOIN obligations O 
        ON O.service_id = R.service_id 
    LEFT JOIN persons P  
        ON O.user_id = P.id 
        AND O.active = 0                    -- MOVED FROM WHERE CLAUSE
    LEFT JOIN services S 
        ON O.service_id = S.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT user_id,
               service_id, 
               TOTAL(value) AS fee
        FROM fees
        WHERE active = 0
        GROUP BY user_id,
                 service_id
    ) C ON C.user_id = P.id
        AND C.service_id = O.service_id
    WHERE R.id = 3
```

Comment: Should the aggregation be on user_id and service_id?

Comment: Thank you! I just had to pull the C.service_id column as well, otherwise it'd complain when trying to use it on the aggregation; and wrap the C.fee with IFNULL() to make sure that, in case no extra fee is found, it won't break the operation with it's 'NULL' value, but it will be read as 0 instead.