# How to get data from a calculated column in a select used in an insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have one table like this. In this table, Balance Column is calculated from data of another table when insert, and Rate is calculated from Balance.

```
Id   Name   Balance   Rate
1     AAA    1000     200
```

Balance: from data of another table.
Rate: Balance x 0.2

```
INSERT INTO TableA (Name, Balance, Rate)
SELECT
   'AAA' AS Name,
   ((Score + 100) * 3) - 20 as Balance
   Balance * 0.2 as Rate    <--- Instead of (((Score + 100) * 3) - 20) *0.2 
FROM TableB where PKey = 1
```

My question is, since Balance is calculated when insert, it seems that I’m not able to get the value for Rate on the same SELECT command? (If not repeat the same calculation of Balance on Rate Column)
Is it possible to use one command to insert complete data?
Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you show us the insert command

Comment: And with complete insert statement, please provide output you get (what is inserted) and what you want to be inserted (desired output)

Comment: Check this question which has an answer to what you are asking. [How to use a calculated column to calculate another column in the same view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185043/how-to-use-a-calculated-column-to-calculate-another-column-in-the-same-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query on the result of another query, look at this example

```
select t.Name,
       t.Balance,
       t.Balance * 0.2 as Rate
from   ( SELECT 'AAA' AS Name,
                ((Score + 100) * 3) - 20 as Balance
         FROM   TableB 
         where  PKey = 1
       ) as t
```

For large queries and complicated calculations this can make the query more readable, there should be no affect on the performance

Look at [this DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h6ZssNw3) to see how it works