# can sqlite UPDATE staments be processed line-by-line to help solve "sqlite calculate columns based on columns"

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, calculated-columns

I have a table which includes large number of calculated columns based on other calculated columns. So there are:

x, f(x),g(f(x)),h(g(x)... and so on. Each function uses a large number of fields, so that writing out the formulas from first principles is tedious and error-prone.

I am aware of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244029/how-to-use-a-calculated-column-by-another-calculated-column) using sub-queries. However, this becomes increasingly impractical as columns become calculated based on other calculated columns which themselves are calculated.  You would need a subquery for every level of calculation. For wide tables like mine, this would be prone to error.

I thought of a different solution, which is firstly to fill the calculated columns with dummy numbers, and then use UPDATE to calculate columns in the sequence desired.

Here is a MWE (not the real thing):

```
create table a (x ,y,z);
insert into  a(x,y,z)
    values (1,1,1),(2,1,1);
update a
    set y = x, 
    z = 7 * y;
select * from a;
```

Currently this doesn't work, and the calculation for `z` uses the un-refreshed value of y.

To solve this, I have to separate the update statements

```
update a
    set y = 3 * x;
update a
    set z = 7 * y;
```

My question: is there any way to tell SQLITE to complete the calculations for the first line in the UPDATE statement, and then proceeed, so I can bundle all my calculations under one UPDATE statement?

Answer (score 1):

The only database I know that uses the changed values of columns in expressions in an `UPDATE` statement is MySql.
The standard behavior is to use the stored values.
In your case there is an easy solution.
The new value for `y` is `3 * x` so instead of:

```
z = 7 * y
```

use:

```
z = 7 * (3 * x)
```

or

```
z = 21 * x
```

and your statement will be:

```
update a
set y = 3 * x, 
    z = 21 * x;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/upGUeRvup2buvcorobsBJ4/0).
Results:

```
| x   | y   | z   |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 3   | 21  |
| 2   | 6   | 42  |
```

Comment: ok, so mysql differs from other sql's.  That's handy to know.
My example was supposed to be a MWE using a trivial function.  I should have made this clearer (will edit now).  In reality, x and y and z (and there are many more) are complicated functions of (calculated) columns; so I can't use the 'easy solution'.