# Nested calculations in SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

I have a SQLite table with buy and sell prices in different currencies. Something like

```
CREATE TABLE ins_and_outs 
(
    prod_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    buy_price DECIMAL,
    buy_currency TEXT,
    buy_currency_EUR DECIMAL NOT NULL,
    sell_price DECIMAL,
    sell_currency TEXT,
    sell_currency_EUR DECIMAL
)
```

I need to calculate

1. the buy and sell prices in Eur (multiply 2 columns);
2. then take the previous values and calculate the difference (profit)
3. and finally take the difference and the calculated buy value and calculate the profit %

This requires referencing back to calculated values to calculate the next ones, hypothetically

```
SELECT buy_price * buy_currency_EUR AS buy_Eur, sell_price * sell_currency_EUR AS sell_Eur, sell_Eur - buy_Eur AS profit, profit / buy_Eur * 100 AS pct
```

Only this is not accepted and I don't want to repeat the calculations in every column if I can find a better solution.

This can be done easily assigning the SQL output to an external array or object of course, but I was looking into doing everything within the database, using one or more views.

I had a look at using [sub-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244029/how-to-use-a-calculated-column-by-another-calculated-column), but I would need to get the values from the same table row in the sub-query as the main query and I don't see how to do that, given that all the examples I found work with fixed values or values from other tables in the sub-query. I'm also thinking a solution using sub-queries would make the SQL statement very hard to read and troubleshoot in the future.

One alternative would be to create 2 views, the first calculates the sell prices in Eur and the second view takes the first as input and calculates the rest. Would this work? Also, can a nested view update all the way back to the original tables?

Another alternative would be to add the calculated columns to the table and trigger the calculations on `UPDATE`. This would use more disk space but require less CPU every time the data is accessed.

Most importantly, what would be the best solution for this case?

Comment: You can use Lag function. https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-lag/

Comment: From what I understand, LAG helps with calculations across multiple rows, and in my case all calculations are done with values from the same row. Do you mean setting the offset as 0? I still don't see how this could be used to reference calculated values in the same statement.

Comment: That is what I understood out of "This requires referencing back to calculated values to calculate the next ones.". Please add some sample data and from it what would be the result you are expecting. Here is a good reference on how to set up your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/460557

Comment: If all you need is to calculate values from the current row just use the fields and do math on it, for instance: `select (buy_price * sell_price) fsCalc, (buy_price * sell_price)/100 ndCalc, ((buy_price * sell_price) - ((buy_price * sell_price)/100)) rdCalc...` and so on

Comment: I edited the post for clarity, adding an example and another possible solution.

Comment: you can't use the Aliases you created on the same select statement. Just repeat the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as mentioned in the comments in the `SELECT` statement section of your query you can not reuse the aliases you defined there:

```
SELECT buy_price * buy_currency_EUR AS buy_Eur, -- buy_Eur is an alias not a column 
       sell_price * sell_currency_EUR AS sell_Eur -- same here, 
       sell_Eur - buy_Eur AS profit, 
       profit / buy_Eur * 100 AS pct
FROM yourTable
```

So in order to solve your problem the easiest way is to repeat the calculations and make sure to use parenthesis:

```
SELECT buy_price * buy_currency_EUR AS buy_Eur, 
       sell_price * sell_currency_EUR AS sell_Eur, 
       (sell_price * sell_currency_EUR) - (buy_price * buy_currency_EUR) AS profit, 
       (((sell_price * sell_currency_EUR) - (buy_price * buy_currency_EUR)) / (buy_price * buy_currency_EUR) * 100) AS pct
FROM yourTable
```

The other way of doing it is using sub queries, but you would need more than one which doesn't make sense IMHO (I will show just one level):

```
SELECT buy_Eur, sell_Eur, 
       sell_Eur - buy_Eur as profit,
       (sell_Eur - buy_Eur) / buy_Eur * 100 as pct
FROM (
   SELECT buy_price * buy_currency_EUR AS buy_Eur, 
          sell_price * sell_currency_EUR AS sell_Eur 
     FROM yourTable
) as sub -- you need to name (alias) your subquery
```

EDIT:
One more option is to create a view of your query and query it like a simple table:

```
CREATE VIEW yourViewName as
SELECT buy_price * buy_currency_EUR AS buy_Eur, 
       sell_price * sell_currency_EUR AS sell_Eur, 
       (sell_price * sell_currency_EUR) - (buy_price * buy_currency_EUR) AS profit, 
       (((sell_price * sell_currency_EUR) - (buy_price * buy_currency_EUR)) / (buy_price * buy_currency_EUR) * 100) AS pct
FROM yourTable;
```

Then just use:

```
select buy_Eur, sell_Eur, profit, pct 
from yourViewName
```

Comment: Obrigado Jorge Campos. I think I'm going to add extra columns for the calculated values. That way the calculations are done only once, and after that it's just reading stored data. What would you do?

Comment: I would recommend against it. You don't need to store the data that can be calculated. Storing the data will consume resources of your system calculating it wont cause any performance issues. Also the advantage of having it calculated is that you don't need to worry about updating those fields as well which would also consumes resources.
If you just want to make your query more readable just create a view of it. I will edit my answer adding it

Comment: ooh, and "de nada" (our "you are welcome" equivalent :) )